# CSS How to center an item in Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I am using Ionic3, and have the following:

[image]

I would like to center align the ion-card.

**html**

```
  <div class="contracted-content">

  <ion-card class="job-card">

    ...

  </ion-card>

  <div class="person-job">
    <ion-row>

      ...

    </ion-row>
  </div>

 </div>
```

**scss**

```
.contracted-content {
    max-width: 369px;
    align-content: center;    
}
```

As you can see, I set the max width to 369px, so that the image does not distort. Now, when the browsers width gets increased beyond the 369px, I would like to center the `div` (the `align-content: center;` has no affect).

Any advise appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "margin: 0 auto;" ?

Comment: Thanks `margin: 0 auto;` works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `margin: 0 auto;` to center your element

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/uf0bq4dm/)**

**CSS**

```
.align-center{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-card class="job-card align-center">
 ...
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try `translateX(-50%);` it seems to push half of the card off the left of the page.

Comment: I have on the advise above tried `margin: 0 auto;`, and it works.

Comment: @Richard you need to set relative position (see my demo), but if the other solution works for you, use the other :)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to go with `margin: 0 auto;`